# How to pass multiple values from child to parent process using signals in C?

Tags: c, process, signals, fork

I have to pass 3 separate values, say "10", "15", "20" that are stored in a child process to a parent process. I cannot use shared memory or pipes, only signals and handlers. How do I pass these values from a child to parent only using signals? I tried passing exit codes but you can only have one exit value. I need to pass 3 separate values. Any suggestions? In addition, my parent has two children. Both of these children have to pass 3 separate values of their own to the parent, so that the parent can add them in the end.

Comment: Why do you have there ridiculous constrains?

Comment: My professor is crazy. haha!

Comment: This might help : http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Signaling-Another-Process.html#Signaling-Another-Process
If you're wondering how to send values, just use two different signals and send binary values

Comment: I'm tempted to close-vote but I can't find the "this is a damn stupid idea" reason :-)

Comment: well, if the only means to pass is using signals, then passing values as exit codes is not affordable, as `exit(2)` system call doesn't use the signal passing way.  PLEASE, EDIT YOUR QUESTION AND WRITE A PROPER REQUIREMENT, AS THE ONE USED IS AMBIGUOUS AND UNCLEAR. Voted for close, as unclear question.

Comment: @ElizabethC, the problem you are posting is far more difficult to solve, exclusively with signals, than required from a beginners course on unix.  Probably you have missed something or your teacher has not expressed correctly the exercise.   Please, ask him for a clarification.

Comment: @Pablo, constraints are far from ridiculous.  The problem, that can be solved in several ways, with just only one signal type (better with a minimum of two different signal types) is a quite complex one, as it requires to develop a comms protocol to do sender synchronization and the like.  I think this is a homework for a unix beginners course, and so, it's far out of scope.

Comment: @paxdiablo, I agree on the _stupid idea_, anyway :)

Comment: @LuisColorado *... is a quite complex one, as it requires to develop a comms protocol to do sender synchronization and the like. I think this is a homework for a unix beginners course, and so, it's far out of scope.* That's why I say it's a ridiculous constrain, when you can easily write the program using shared memory or pipes.

Comment: @Pablo, indeed to learn, the constraint is not ridiculous.... indeed is quite amazing to solve a problem like this.  But it's far out of scope for a unix beginner's class.

Comment: @ElizabethC, when is your deadline? so I can guess if I can be able to work a solution to comply with it.

Comment: Deadline is this Saturday! This is a continuation of our first project. The first project we had to use shared memory which I did so easily. But now the next part of the project is to replace shared memory and only use signals. Which I am completely stuck on !

Comment: This is for my intro to Operating Systems course at my University. My professor is pretty difficult and likes to challenge us I guess..

Comment: You'll get the answer on sunday then... sorry, but being a scholar work, challenges have their value, and I don't want to break your teacher intentions.  I have already written the code, but I'm afraid this is not the way your teacher wants the problem solved.  My apologies for the delay.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as I promised in one of the comments, here's a solution to the problem.  The first thing to say is that this solution does not work properly in Linux, as linux makes no warrant of signal delivery on high number of signals sent (when the target process doesn't get scheduled enough to handle them) so a BSD version has been used (also should run, but not tested on Mac OS/X and other unices).  I'll explain the solution achieved in four steps, as the first probably is enough to pass the homework, but not enough to consider it a proper working way of passing information from child to parent. Also, due to limited space to post code, I've posted only the first version of the code and all the others must be downloaded from github (links provided).

The implementation has been made on a raspberry pi with freebsd 11.0 which makes delivery of signals reliable.  The failing system was a Debian 9.4 with kernel version 4.9.0-6-amd64

## FIRST VERSION

As the homework problem states, the only thing the parent is to do is to add the numbers and print the result.  Then, a good plan is to encode a number, `N`, to the parent, as sending `n` signals of type `SIGUSR1`.  The parent has only to count the signals and print the number when the child finishes (we determine this on a succesful return from the `wait(2)` system call)

## child.c

```
/* 00001 */ #include <sys/types.h>
/* 00002 */ #include <sys/time.h>
/* 00003 */ #include <signal.h>
/* 00004 */ #include <stdio.h>
/* 00005 */ #include <stdlib.h>
/* 00006 */ #include <unistd.h>
/* 00007 */ #include <time.h>

/* 00008 */ #define F(fmt) "<%d>:"__FILE__":%d:%s: " fmt, my_pid, __LINE__, __func__

/* 00009 */ pid_t my_pid;

/* 00010 */ int main()
/* 00011 */ {
/* 00012 */         pid_t parent_pid = getppid();
/* 00013 */         struct timeval now;
/* 00014 */         gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
/* 00015 */         srand((int)now.tv_sec ^ (int)now.tv_usec);
/* 00016 */         my_pid = getpid();
/* 00017 */         int sum = 0;

/* 00018 */         int n = rand() % 3 + 1;
/* 00019 */         int i;
/* 00020 */         for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
/* 00021 */                 int number = rand() % 10 + 10;
/* 00022 */                 printf(F("Sending %d\n"), number);
/* 00023 */                 int j;
/* 00024 */                 for (j = 0; j < number; j++) {
/* 00025 */                         printf(F("kill(%d, SIGUSR1);\n"), parent_pid);
/* 00026 */                         kill(parent_pid, SIGUSR1);
/* 00027 */                 }
/* 00028 */                 sum += number;
/* 00029 */         }
/* 00030 */         printf(F("my sum = %d\n"), sum);
/* 00031 */ }
```

(each child selects at random a number between 1 and 4 numbers, randomly in the range 10...19, and sends that number of `SIGUSR1` signals to the parent)

The parent is so:

## parent.c

```
/* 00001 */ #include <errno.h>
/* 00002 */ #include <signal.h>
/* 00003 */ #include <stdio.h>
/* 00004 */ #include <stdlib.h>
/* 00005 */ #include <string.h>
/* 00006 */ #include <sys/time.h>
/* 00007 */ #include <sys/types.h>
/* 00008 */ #include <sys/wait.h>
/* 00009 */ #include <time.h>
/* 00010 */ #include <unistd.h>

/* 00011 */ #define F(fmt) "[%d]:"__FILE__":%d:%s: " fmt, my_pid, __LINE__, __func__

/* 00012 */ #define NCHILDREN 8

/* 00013 */ char child[] = "child";

/* 00014 */ pid_t my_pid;

/* 00015 */ int sum = 0; /* here's where the number of signals is accumulated */

/* 00016 */ void handler(int sig, siginfo_t *info, void *unused)
/* 00017 */ {
/* 00018 */         switch (sig) {
/* 00019 */         case SIGUSR1: sum++; break;
/* 00020 */         }
/* 00021 */ }

/* 00022 */ int main()
/* 00023 */ {
/* 00024 */         int i;

/* 00025 */         my_pid = getpid();

/* 00026 */         struct sigaction sa, oldsa; 
/* 00027 */         sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
/* 00028 */         sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART; /* restart the wait(2) syscall below */
/* 00029 */         sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
/* 00030 */         sigaddset(&sa.sa_mask, SIGUSR1);
/* 00031 */         sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, &oldsa);

/* 00032 */         pid_t res;

/* 00033 */         for (i = 0; i < NCHILDREN; i++) {
/* 00034 */                 res = fork();
/* 00035 */                 if (res > 0) /* parent */
/* 00036 */                         continue;
/* 00037 */                 else if (res < 0) {
/* 00038 */                         fprintf(stderr,
/* 00039 */                                 F("ERROR: fork: %s (errno = %d)\n"),
/* 00040 */                                 strerror(errno), errno);
/* 00041 */                         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
/* 00042 */                 } else { /* child */
/* 00043 */                         execlp(child, child, NULL);
/* 00044 */                         fprintf(stderr,
/* 00045 */                                 F("ERROR: exec: %s: %s (errno = %d)\n"),
/* 00046 */                                 child, strerror(errno), errno);
/* 00047 */                         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
/* 00048 */                 }
/* 00049 */         }

/* 00050 */         while (wait(NULL) >= 0); /* wait for children until no more */

/* 00051 */         sigaction(SIGUSR1, &oldsa, NULL);

/* 00052 */         printf(F("sum = %d\n"), sum);
/* 00053 */ }
```

This example will make the parent to print the correct sum, as you can probe (linux fails dramatically printing in some cases just `sum = 1`, because it is only capable of processing the first signal of each type, leading to a single number of value 1)  The problem with linux is that linux cannot ensure and deliver several signals if the receiver has not been scheduled enough for the system to be able to the signals and allow the handler to be called. Just inserting a `sleep(1)` in `child.c` after the `kill(2)` syscall of line `60` will do.

Many readers will complaint about the way the solution is implemented, as this is not a good way to pass info to the parent (no form of delimiting the numbers themselves to allow the parent to separate and identify them), and some way to differentiate the different numbers passed and someway to identify the sender to be included.  So the parent not only wants to print the sum, but also which number comes from which child or a way to separate the different numbers for each child.

## SECOND VERSION(first attempt)

In this version, we introduce the `sigaction(2)` syscall and its possibility of getting in the signal handler a way to identify the sender of such signal (`SA_SIGINFO` POSIX option).  I refer the reader to the manual page, as it is well documented there (even for linux, that continues to handle signals without warrant the signal delivery) and [files can be downloaded from here](https://github.com/mojadita/signals/tree/V2)

Parent is far more complicated.  It has a table for each child and a handler that extracts the signal's sender pid, searches for the child slot, and stores in it the accumulated number of signals received, and handling the `SIGUSR2` signal as an end of data marker, that allows us to store the accumulated value.

The parent now prints the numbers received from each child and, if you try this example, **you'll see another issue**:  The kernel does not warrant the order in which signals are delivered.  This means that some `SIGUSR1` signals belonging to a next number are handled before the `SIGUSR2` signal finishing the previous number.  So we cannot send new `SIGUSR1` signals until the last `SIGUSR2` signal has been sent *and handled*.  We correct this introducing a delay `sleep(1)` in the next version:

## THIRD VERSION (with delays)

On this version we introduce delays into the child program, so no number is sent until we have given time to the parent to handle all the pending signals.  In this way, no `SIGUSR2` corresponding to a next number is sent to the parent process before it has had time to process it.  [These are the files for this version](https://github.com/mojadita/signals/tree/V3_delays/)

In this case, you'll observe the output is delayed at several points to allow for the parent to have the time to deliver pending signals before sending new ones.

## VERSION FOUR (final version)

Our final approach tries to eliminate the delays, making the parent to send a signal to the child as soon as he has received a `SIGUSR2`, indicating the end of a number, to acknowledge the reception of the number and to allow the child to continue.  I'll comment at the end some race condition, that can be saved with some code already included on it (As i'm limited in post space, I'll publish it on github and [allow you to download it from there](https://github.com/mojadita/signals))

## COMMENT ON THE RACE CONDITION

On final version, there's an unavoidable race condition in the child, as we cannot enable interrupts while in `pause(2)` syscall, so we cannot enter in the `pause(2)` system call with interrupts blocked, to unblock them inside and listen for the next interrupt. The lines in `child.c`:

```
00061:      printf(F("kill(%d, SIGUSR2);\n"), parent_pid);
00062:      sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sa.sa_mask, NULL);
00063:      yet_unacknowledged = 1;
00064:      kill(parent_pid, SIGUSR2);
00065:      sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &sa.sa_mask, NULL);
00066:      while (yet_unacknowledged) sleep(1);
```

allow for the parent to be scheduled, send the ack signal, and the signal be handled between the check for `yet_unacknowledged` in the while loop and the `sleep(1)` statement.  These lines where written initially as:

```
00066:      pause();  /* wait for an interrupt */
```

but this way, sometimes the child gets blocked as the acknowledge signal has been delivered (and handled) between the `kill` from the child to the parent and the `pause(2)` syscall.

But after checking that there's no way to enable `SIGUSR2` interrupts while executing `pause()` the only way to proceed is to consider that the handler has executed in between and execute just single `sleep(1)` once.  Next loop pass, the check will fail and, at most we execute only one `sleep` call.

## How to implement all of this in linux

Well, I have extended far more from my original target, and I will not show a complete working solution in linux.  As linux cannot ensure that more of one signal is warranted to be delivered to a process, the only way to implement is to install a mechanism for the parent to acknowledge each received signal, and the child not to send the next signal until it has received the acknowledge of the previous.  This is completeley out of scope for a beginners course on introduction to system calls (better on a course of networking protocols), so if you are interested, you'll have to ask your teacher for more info on this.

Answer (score 0):

Send signal from child to parent using [rt_sigqueueinfo()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rt_sigqueueinfo.2.html). You can use [sigqueue()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sigqueue.3.html) as well.

Please refer this example
[send signal to parent with data](https://github.com/aditya723/system-programming/blob/master/send_data_using_signal.c)

Comment: while the `rt_sigqueueinfo()` is a linux (specific???) syscall that allows the target process to identify the pid of the sinding process, the coding of a solution using those syscalls is far out of scope, as those syscalls don't have C bindings in glibc (this is noted in the man page you posted in your comment) so a workaround should be made in assembler to use them.  IMHO the teacher has different requirements or the poster has not understood the exact requirements.

Comment: the example you post to illustrate uses shared memory segments to pass the information to the parent.  I assume this is out of scope from the message posted.

Comment: Can you specifically tell where example that i posted uses shared memory segments.

Comment: yes, rt_sigqueueinfo() is linux specific, we can use sigqueue() as substitute for that. I also mentioned sigqueue().

Comment: Nope, just `sigaction(2)` in POSIX mode, allows you to identify the sender of the signal, so no bus reservation protocol has to be implemented to differentiate.... but anyway, the problem is far out of scope in a unix beginners course.